# Does Apache httpclient support multipart\related?

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

By default Apache Http client MIME API version 4.3.2 sends the content type as multipart/form-data. Is there any other way to change the content type as multipart-related?

Answer (score 2):

This is the recommended way of building requests with a multipart entity of any subtype

```
HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
        .setMimeSubtype("related")
        .addPart(...)
        .addPart(...)
        .addPart(...)
        .build();
HttpRequest request = RequestBuilder.post("/stuff")
        .setEntity(entity)
        .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to set the value of the header yourself:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(SAMPLE_URL);
request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "multipart/related");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation which work for me :
I have set the type to application/octet-stream since I do not know what kind of data you are uploading.. fell free to change this.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


public class UploadMimeMultipartRelated  {

    /** Logger. */
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UploadMimeMultipartRelated.class);

    /** Mime type */
    private static final String CONTENT_TYPE_MULTIPART = "multipart/related";
    private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "application/octet-stream";
    private static final String BOUNDARY = "--upload_boundary--";

    private static final String URL = "http://.....";

    @Override
    public void uploadFiles(List<String> filePathlist) {

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

        MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().setBoundary(BOUNDARY);
        for (String filepath : filePathlist) {
            multipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody("file_upload", new File(filepath), ContentType.create(CONTENT_TYPE), "filename");
        }
        HttpEntity entity = multipartEntityBuilder.build();


        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
        httpPost.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, CONTENT_TYPE_MULTIPART+";type="+CONTENT_TYPE+";boundary="+BOUNDARY);
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);


        CloseableHttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            response.getEntity();
            response.close();
            httpClient.close();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            LOG.error("ClientProtocolException during upload",e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error("IOException during upload",e);
        }

    }
```